# Rollback Stored Procedure in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, savepoints

I got a requirement where I have to rollback a stored procedure based on a condition.

First i call the stored procedure and later check a condition and if condition fails, have to rollback. Below is the code I have tried.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student=new Student();

    student.setName("AAAA");
    student.setAge("20");
    student.setDob("14/08/1988");
    student.setPhone("98841");
    student.setSslc("1111");
    student.setHsc("222");
    student.setCollege("333");
    System.out.println(student);
    try {
        Connection conn=ConnectDB.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        String proc = "{call STUDENT_OP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(proc);
        Savepoint savepoint1 = conn.setSavepoint("ROLLBACK_SP");

        int age=Integer.parseInt(student.getAge());

        callableStatement.setString(1, student.getName());
        callableStatement.setInt(2, age);
        callableStatement.setString(3, student.getDob());
        callableStatement.setString(4, student.getPhone());
        callableStatement.setString(5, student.getSslc());
        callableStatement.setString(6, student.getHsc());
        callableStatement.setString(7, student.getCollege());
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);

        callableStatement.executeUpdate();

        int returnCode=callableStatement.getInt(8);
        getStudents();

        if(SOME CONDITION){
            conn.rollback(savepoint1);
        }
        getStudents();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the above code, **getStudents()** method prints the list of name in **student** table. Am running this **getStudents()** method before rollback and after rollback. I have set the **Savepoint** as **Savepoint savepoint1 = conn.setSavepoint("ROLLBACK_SP");** and am rolling back using this savepoint.

But rollback is not happening. Am I missing something? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) component from ui-bootstrap.